# javascript source map : keeping map file local only to debug production javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, source-maps

I would like to debug production website, but I don't want to upload the map file on the server (for privacy reason, because it is public right ?).

Is it possible ?

Comment: What are your privacy concerns for the map file, considering all of the JavaScript code is public, anyways?

Answer (score 17):

I don't believe any browsers currently allow loading source maps ondemand from local files, so you have to put the sourcemaps online somehow.

One solution could be to create a .htaccess file (or something similar, if you aren't using Apache) that restricts access to the sourcemap (and the original source files) to clients that aren't from your local network.

You should realize though, that if you want to prevent access to the sourcemaps for security reasons, then all you will achieve is a false sense of safety. Javascript is public, and even if it is minified and encrypted, it is fairly easy to unencrypt it. Do **not** put any sensitive data in your javascript. Not even if you minify and encrypt it.

Comment: It won't run if it is encrypted, I think you mean [obfuscated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_%28software%29)?

Comment: Obfuscation, of course, could be unraveled just by passing the code through a beautifier, but I guess my point is that no matter what you would think of, you would still be sending all your code and data to the client. So, even if you create some kind of amazing encryption scheme, you would still need to send the means to unencrypt it to the client because, as you say, otherwise the client won't be able to run it. All an attacker would have to do is put a breakpoint in sometime after the 'secret' data have been unencrypted.

Comment: It's not really about hiding sensitive data, it's about raising the effort required to rip off your functionality.

Answer (score 5):

Following might be useful for you

[Multi-level Source Maps](http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/multi-level-sourcemaps) - The CSS Ninja

The link also explains using [UglifyJS2](https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS2) with which an input source map can be specified. However, I have not tested with a local input source

Also, you can try hosting the file on local and changing your `hosts` file to point something like `local.mydomain.com` to `localhost`. And then specify `local.mydomain.com/js/my-orig-js-file.js` as the Source Root

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to upload the map file and the minified js on the server and keep the original js file locally. Then modify your map file in something like this:

```
{
    "version":3,
    "sources":["http://localhost/library.js"],
    "names":["example","console","log"],
    "mappings":"AAAA,QAASA,YACRC,QAAQC,IAAI","file":"script.min.js"
}
```